# Is Gawain related to Escanor and Merlin?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

The Gawain character looks like a fusion of the Merlin and Escanor characters (the strength of Escanor and the magic of Merlin) . The Spanish Nanatsu no Taizai wiki claims she's the daughter of both of them, which I doubt because the English wikia says nothing.
[Gawain - Nanatsu no Taizai Spanish wikia](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/es/wiki/Gawain)

Also, this other article in a prestigious Spanish sports magazine, which uploaded an anime article for some reason, claims she's the daughter of Diane and King [Who are the 4 knights of the Apocalypse - Mundo Deportivo](https://www.mundodeportivo.com/alfabeta/the-seven-deadly-sins/quienes-son-los-cuatro-jinetes-de-nanatsu-no-taizai)

Is Gawain related to Escanor and Merlin? How about to Diane and King?